# Kuebernetes - remove default certificate on ingress

Tags: ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress

I have the following nginx ingress defined:

```
[root@WekaMgmtServer log]# kubectl -n home-test-io describe ing 

Name:             test-home-ingress 

Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm 

Namespace:        home-test-io 

Address:          localhost 

Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>) 

TLS: 

  SNI routes testhome.blah.com 

  test-home-ingress-cert-secret terminates 

Rules: 

  Host        Path  Backends 

  ----        ----  -------- 

  * 

              /stats/.*                        homewekaio-grafana:3000 (172.17.0.19:3000) 

              /api/.*/clusters/.*/stats        home-test-io-stats-handler:8001 (172.17.0.22:8000) 

              /api/.*/clusters/.*/support/.*   home-test-io-diags-handler:8002 (172.17.0.32:8000) 

              /api/.*                          home-test-io-api:8000 (172.17.0.24:8000,172.17.0.25:8000) 

              /.*                              home-test-io-frontend:80 (172.17.0.12:80) 

Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx 

              meta.helm.sh/release-name: hometest 

              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: home-test-io 

              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: http 

              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-access-log: true 

              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: true 

              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-modsecurity: true 

              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-owasp-core-rules: true 

              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 1000m 

              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: off 

              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: false 

              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true 

Events:       <none>
```

Note that the above indicates SNI routes to testhome.blah.com and is terminated by the test-home-ingress-cert-secret. Despite this, whenever I browse to testhome.blah.com, the default, self-signed, Kubernetes certificate is displayed, not the one stored by the test-home-ingress-cert-secret secret. Why would this be?

I would expect the certificate stored in the test-home-ingress-cert-secret secret to be the certificate displayed when browsing to testhome.blah.com.